# Schema.org payment and delivery methods in site footer

Tags: schema.org, payments, footer

I have create an online shop for bikes. In the footer are the payment methods like VISA, MASTERCARD and PAYPAL, including delivery and collection methods.

Which schemas from Schema.org should use I to markup payment and delivery methods in the footer? But bare in mind that this content is repeated on every page.

Answer (score 2):

For an `Offer` (i.e., a bike) you can provide the [`acceptedPaymentMethod` property](http://schema.org/acceptedPaymentMethod) and the [`availableDeliveryMethod` property](http://schema.org/availableDeliveryMethod):

- `acceptedPaymentMethod` takes enumeration URIs from [`PaymentMethod`](http://schema.org/PaymentMethod) (including [`CreditCard`](http://schema.org/CreditCard)) as value.
- `availableDeliveryMethod` takes enumeration URIs from [`DeliveryMethod`](http://schema.org/DeliveryMethod) (including [`LockerDelivery`](http://schema.org/LockerDelivery) and [`ParcelService`](http://schema.org/ParcelService)) as value.

In Microdata, it could look like this for your case:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemref="payment-methods delivery-methods">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Nice bike</h1>
</article>

<footer>

  <div id="payment-methods">
    <p>Payment methods: MasterCard, PayPal, VISA.</p>
    <link itemprop="acceptedPaymentMethod" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#MasterCard" />
    <link itemprop="acceptedPaymentMethod" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#PayPal" />
    <link itemprop="acceptedPaymentMethod" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#VISA" />
  </div>

  <div id="delivery-methods">
    <p>Delivery methods: UPS.</p>
    <link itemprop="availableDeliveryMethod" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#UPS " />
  </div>

</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
<footer>
    <ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PaymentMethod">
        <li itemprop="name">
            MASTERCARD
        </li>
        <li itemprop="name">
            VISA
        </li>
        <li itemprop="name">
            CASH
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/DeliveryMethod">
        <span itemprop="name">DHL</span>
        <span itemprop="description">We use DHL to send parcels anywhere in the world, we do however allow collections from our shop.</span>
    </div>
</footer>
```