# Why use meta for some Schema markup?

Tags: html, meta-tags, schema.org

I don't quite understand why some Schema.org examples use `<meta>` instead of say `<span>`. For example:

```
<meta itemprop="startDate" content="2016-04-21T20:00">
    Thu, 04/21/16
    8:00 p.m.
```

Source: https://schema.org/Event

If my current markup is:

```
<li>Jan 13-15, 2016</li>
```

Do I need to use `meta` or can I just add the Schema `itemprop` and `content` stuff inside the `<li>`? And what's the reason so I know when I will need to use the `<meta>`?

Comment: Best to follow https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/events on Events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Microdata, `meta` and `link` elements should be used if you don’t want to display the value of the property on your page.

This is typically the case for properties that expect a value that is not human-readable, for example [URIs that represent accepted payment/delivery methods](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/85554/17633) (= good case for `link`), or [ISO 4217 codes that represent currencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21504996/1591669) (= good case for `meta`).

---

The example with the `startDate` property would ideally use the `time` element instead, as this is what should be used for dates/times, and it allows to specify the machine-readable format in the `datetime` attribute:

```html
<time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2016-04-21T20:00">
    Thu, 04/21/16
    8:00 p.m.
</time>
```

For your own example, you could also use `time` elements, but because of your chosen format, it might not be very elegant:

```html
<li>
  Jan <time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2016-01-13">13</time>-<time itemprop="endDate" datetime="2016-01-15">15</time>, 2016
</li>
```

The alternative with `meta` elements could look like:

```html
<li>
  Jan 13-15, 2016 
  <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2016-01-13" /> 
  <meta itemprop="endDate" content="2016-01-15" />
</li>
```

Which one of those to use is a semantic markup question; it doesn’t affect the extracted Microdata/Schema.org.